# Isolated Scope in Angular Card Flip Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing a directive for card flipping in AngularJs.

- HTML(Jade)

  ```
  card
                  display
                      | this is sid
                      input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Save',ng-click="flip()")
                  editor
                      | this is test
                      input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Save',ng-click="flip()")

              card
                  display hey siddharth
                  editor  huu ulujh
  ```
- Directive

  ```
  'card': function ()
  {
  return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {

          var options = {
              flipDuration: ($attrs.flipDuration) ? $attrs.flipDuration : 400,
              timingFunction: 'ease-in-out'
          };


          angular.forEach(['display', 'editor'], function(name) {
              var el = $elem.find(name);
              if (el.length == 1) {
                  angular.forEach(['', '-ms-', '-webkit-'], function(prefix) {
                      angular.element(el[0]).css(prefix + 'transition', 'all ' + options.flipDuration/1000 + 's ' + options.timingFunction);
                  });
              }
          });


          $scope.flip = function() {
              $elem.toggleClass('flipped');
          }

      }
  };
  }
  ```

The problem is: if I use just one instance of directive i.e like in above html just the top directive with buttons, it works fine. But When I have multiple instances of the directive as shown above, Single click from the above instance flips all the instances.

This should not be the case. flip should be limited/restricted to its own scope. I tried isolating the scope of directive by adding scope: {}, above link function but still no effect.

Please if someone could guide me how to do it right.

Edit:
[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/372da6O25hOrBxpT0oX2?p=preview) -- http://plnkr.co/edit/372da6O25hOrBxpT0oX2?p=preview

Help Appreciated :-)

Comment: Can you make a live example? Here as a snippet, or on plunkr, or something...

Comment: Here is the code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/372da6O25hOrBxpT0oX2?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `scope: true` instead of `scope: {}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why this is not an answer? if the user does that i said he will be able to resolve his problem. He's asking for a problem solution and i answered with a solution. As well as you can see i can't comment to his post cos i've got not enought reputation. So if i want to help i need to create an answer.

Comment: @nada: Thanks! scope: true, got it working. If you could guide me with the other expected behavior mentioned on plunker :-)

Comment: so what do you need. Put your flipped content at the same height than your not flipped content? try to edit your .editor class (remove margin and padding, then add top:9px. Dont know if that's you want.